# Calling Mailgun Rest API from Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, mailgun, oracle-apex-5.1

I  use Oracle Apex 19 and need to make a procedure to send mail using Mailgun rest API.

if I write on console the next curl code it work fine:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/example.com.ar/messages' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <<my-secrect-api-code>>' \
--form 'from=postmaster@example.com.ar' \
--form 'to=test@gmail.com' \
--form 'subject=Test' \
--form 'template=mytemplatename'
```

In postman also work correctly:

[image: Postam test]

How I said,  I need translate this code to APEX PL/SQL , I tried

```
    declare
      -- Local variables here
      i      integer;
      l_resp clob;
      g_url  varchar2(300) := 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/example.com.ar/messages';
    
    begin
      -- Test statements here
    
      apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Authorization';
      apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).Value := 'Basic my-secret-code';
    
    
      l_resp := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url         => g_url,
                                                   p_http_method => 'POST',
                                                   p_parm_name  => apex_util.string_to_table('from:to:subject:template',':'),
                                                   p_parm_value => apex_util.string_to_table('postmaster@example.com.ar:test@gmail.com:helo:mytemplate',':'),
                                                   p_wallet_path =>'file:/backup/wallet',
                                                   p_wallet_pwd  => null);
    
    dbms_output.put_line(L_resp);

end;
```

when call the pl/sql procedure I allways get the error:

```
{
  "message": "'from' parameter is missing"
}
```

It sound like FORM parameters is not send, but I dont know how to make this request with APEX_WEB_SERVICE.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the parameters "Content-Type" I've solved the problem:

apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).name := 'Content-Type';
apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).value := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';